# How to update wxTreeListCtrl in real time if the childrens count is more 100000 in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am going to display data in wxTreeListCtrl but i am facing some problems with time ,

it is taking much time  , could some please hep me out of this.

Here is my code:

```
wxTreeListCtrl *m_ptreelistctrl = new wxTreeListCtrl(this, TREELISTCNTRL, pos, size, wxBORDER_NONE|wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS|wxTR_MULTIPLE, validator, name);
m_ptreelistctrl->SetHeaderBackgroundcolour(colour);
//For Displaying Names
m_ptreelistctrl->AddColumn(_U("Description") , 400 ,wxALIGN_LEFT /*,DEFAULT_ITEM_WIDTH, wxALIGN_LEFT */);

//For Displaying ID
    m_ptreelistctrl->AddColumn(_U("Id"), 50/*30*/, wxALIGN_LEFT ,-1 ,false);

//For Displaying Colour
m_ptreelistctrl->AddColumn(_U("Colour"), DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH, wxALIGN_LEFT/*CENTER */);

wxStopWatch *time  = new wxStopWatch();
time->Start();

custTreeItemData* pcusData = new custTreeItemData(-1, TREEITEM_ROOT);
root  = m_ptreelistctrl->AddRoot(m_strRootname, -1,-1,pcusData);

pcusData = new custTreeItemData(-1, TREEITEM_ASSMB);
item_assmb = m_ptreelistctrl->AppendItem( root,"Assem", 0, 3, pcusTrData);
for ( i = 1; i <= 100000; i++ )
    {
        unsigned char r,g,b;
        wxTreeItemId item_assmb_entities;
        custTreeItemData* pcusTrData = new custTreeItemData(i, TREEITEM_ASSMB);
        pcusTrData->SetDataId(10);
        item_assmb_entities = m_ptreelistctrl->AppendItem(item_assmb,"srinvas", 0, 3, pcusTrData);
        FillItems(pcusTrData,item_assmb_entities);
        AppendColorImagetoTree( item_assmb_entities, 2, r, g, b );
        AppendIdtoTree(item_assmb_entities ,1 ,10);
        if( true )
        {
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_assmb_entities, 0, 3 , wxTreeItemIcon_Selected);
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_assmb_entities, 0, 3 );
            pcusTrData->SetCheckStatus(true);
        }
        else
        {
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_assmb_entities, 0, 2 , wxTreeItemIcon_Selected);
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_assmb_entities, 0, 2 ); 
            pcusTrData->SetCheckStatus(false);
        }
    }

pcusData = new custTreeItemData(-1, TREEITEM_COMPS);
item_comp = m_ptreelistctrl->AppendItem( root,"Comps", 0, 3, pcusTrData);

for ( i = 1; i <= 100000; i++ )
    {
        unsigned char r,g,b;
        wxTreeItemId item_comp_entities;
        custTreeItemData* pcusTrData = new custTreeItemData(i, TREEITEM_COMPS);
        pcusTrData->SetDataId(10);
        item_comp_entities= m_ptreelistctrl->AppendItem( item_comp,"Comps", 0, 3, pcusTrData);
        FillItems(pcusTrData,item_comp_entities);
        AppendColorImagetoTree( item_comp_entities, 2, r, g, b );
        AppendIdtoTree(item_comp_entities,1 ,10);
        if( true )
        {
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_comp_entities, 0, 3 , wxTreeItemIcon_Selected);
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_comp_entities, 0, 3 );
            pcusTrData->SetCheckStatus(true);
        }
        else
        {
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_comp_entities, 0, 2 , wxTreeItemIcon_Selected);
            m_ptreelistctrl->SetItemImage( item_comp_entities, 0, 2 );  
            pcusTrData->SetCheckStatus(false);
        }
    }

time->Pause();
int cc = time->Time();
wxString strda;
strda.Printf("time taken%d" ,cc);
wxMessageBox(strda.c_str());
```

Issue: I am going to display more then 200000 childrens but taking time around 17 Minutes

to construct tree ,

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes that you have made sure that the bottleneck is indeed the `wxTreeListCtrl`. It might as well be in your own code, so make sure of this before proceeding!

That being said, I think in this case you are better off using [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) with a custom [wxDataViewModel](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_model.html). The difference is that `wxTreeListCtrl` stores the entire tree in memory and offers no way to batch update the model / view, which might lead to the performance problems. In contrast, `wxDataViewCtrl` is just a view of your own model, which you have to adapt using your own implementation of `wxDataViewModel`. Note that `wxDataViewModel` has functions for batch updating the view, e.g. `ItemsAdded`, `ItemsDeleted`, `ItemsChanged`.

Hope this helps!